# How to create a default value inside column in a list when new items are added, using OOTB workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I want to place one default value in **Hyperlink column** after adding new item to list. For that, I want to use a workflow.

e.g I have one document list in which I have added new **hyperlink column** as default value and now when I am adding new item to list the one value should be placed inside this column.
like

```
Title    Modified   Modified by  Default value
-----    --------   ----------    test
-----    --------   ----------    test
-----    --------   ----------    test
```

Note: test is default value inside the default value column.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To update a hyperlink field using SharePoint designer workflow do like below,

**SPD Workflow > Action > Set Field in Current Item**

```
Set HyperlinkField to  http://google.com, Google
```

This is dynamic dynamic string action, in that construct your url, description value information.

Note: The comma and space are important.

Comment: actually i want that column with hyperlink,n the hyperlinks column isn't showing that property

Comment: that's not working

Comment: How did you do? It works for me perfectly.

Comment: Set Variable: Copy to [%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%] and for this variable the value in string builder is [%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%], [%Current Item:URL%]

Comment: after doing this,when i am trying to add new item to list,then the that field came up with empty textboxes,for inserting url and description

Comment: followd article [https://wonderlaura.com/2013/05/30/workflow-create-a-hyperlink/]

Comment: Use it SPD Workflow > Action > Set Field in Current Item. Dont set workflow variable.